# Error on IIS for ASP.Net Application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-6

I am facing this error occasionally. When I restart the IIS this problem is resolved. The web server(IIS) has more than 10 sites hosted, so i can't restart it simultaneously.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Distributed transaction completed. Either enlist
    this session in a new transaction or the NULL transaction. at 
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean 
    breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException 
    exception, Boolean breakConnection) at 
    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at 
    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, 
    SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject 
    stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() at 
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at 
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior 
    runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at         
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, 
    RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) at 
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior 
    runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) at 
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior 
    runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) at 
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) at 
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() at MyLibrary.LoadDDList(DropDownList& 
    curDDL, String strTextField, String strValueField, String strTable, String svarconditional)
```

Please help me find a solution which preferably doesn't involve restarting IIS.

Comment: have youy tried putting the app into a seperate app pool and recycling it ?

Comment: yes kevin, i have tried it. but it's not working.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the time before worker processes are recycled?

Comment: james, i have tried it as well.

Comment: What is the code that is throwing this exception?

Comment: not particular, the user is facing it any way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function called LoadDDList in the MyLibrary class.

This function needs a Try Catch around the ExecuteReader() command.

```
Try
    mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
Catch sqlException As SqlClient.SqlException
    If sqlException.ErrorCode >= 10 Then
        Throw
    End If
End Try
```

In the catch, you want to check for an ErrorCode less than 10.  If it's less than 10, then it's just a warning message and you can ignore it.  If it's 10 or greater, you need to rethrow it, since it's an actual SQL error (parsing error, invalid table, etc.).

Looking at your stack, this is just a warning and should be ignored.  You need to fix your code so you won't crash IIS when you hit this SQL Warning.